# JS: using capturing with onclick

Tags: javascript

I know when using `addEventListener`, you can add in another argument of `true` to tell it to not bubble and to use capturing instead.  Can this you tell `onclick` to use capture as well when using it instead of `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties of elements like `onclick` are called IDL attributes. See [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes). When its setter is invoked, it [adds the assigned function to the **event handler** map](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#activate-an-event-handler) of the element. That precise name has a very specific meaning here: **"event handlers"** [are](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes):

> Many objects can have event handlers specified. These act as **non-capture** event listeners for the object on which they are specified.

They *always* listen in the bubbling phase, never in the capturing phase. So, what you're looking for isn't possible.

In contrast, `addEventListener` adds an *event listener*, which has a [slightly different official definition](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#add-an-event-listener) and can be either capturing or bubbling.

If you want to add a listener for the capturing phase, you must use `addEventListener`.